# How to do fsync on an ofstream?

Tags: c++, ofstream, fsync

I want to make sure that an ofstream has been written to the disk device. What's the portable way (portable on POSIX systems) of doing this?

Does that solve the problem if I `open` the file separately in <strike>read-only</strike> append mode to get a file descriptor and call `fsync` with it? Like this:

```
ofstream out(filename);
/* ...
   write content into out
   ...
*/
out.close();

int fd = open(filename, O_APPEND);
fsync(fd);
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're able to use Boost, try a file_descriptor_sink based stream, eg.:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

boost::filesystem::path filePath("some-file");
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink> file(filePath);

//  Write some stuff to file.

//  Ensure the buffer's written to the OS ...
file.flush();

//  Tell the OS to sync it with the real device.
//
::fdatasync(file->handle());
```

Comment: Even with the headers I couldn't get this to compile. Has Boost changed since 2014?

Comment: @parsley72, I've just tested it again with Boost 1.80.0; it still works.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, looking through the standard there is nothing provided by `basic_filebuf` or any of the `basic_[io]?fstream` class templates to allow you to extract the underlying OS file descriptor (in the way that `fileno()` does for C stdio I/O).

Nor is there an `open()` method or constructor that takes such a file descriptor as a parameter (which would allow you to open the file using a different mechanism and record the filehandle).

There is `basic_ostream::flush()`, however I suspect that this does not in fact call `fsync()` -- I expect that, like `fflush()` in stdio, it only makes sure that the user-space runtime library buffers are flushed, meaning that the OS could still be buffering the data.

So in short there appears to be no way to do this portably.  :(

What to do?  My suggestion is to subclass `basic_filebuf<C, T>`:

```
template <typename charT, typename traits = std::char_traits<charT> >
class my_basic_filebuf : public basic_filebuf<charT, traits> {
    ....

public:
    int fileno() { ... }
    ....
};

typedef my_basic_filebuf<char> my_filebuf;
```

To use it, you can construct an `ofstream` using the default constructor, then assign the new buffer with `rdbuf()`:

```
my_filebuf buf;
buf.open("somefile.txt");

ofstream ofs;
ofs.rdbuf(&buf);

ofs << "Writing to somefile.txt..." << endl;
int fd = static_cast<my_filebuf*>(ofs.rdbuf())->fileno();
```

Of course you could also derive a new class from `basic_ostream` to make the process of opening a file and retrieving its file descriptor more convenient.

Comment: @BЈовић: (1) It does; I'm not sure what your problem is.  (2) You commented on a post from 2009 1 hour ago and it already has 1 upvote: that doesn't look like a sockpuppet account at all.

Comment: I am not sure how my comment disapeared, but your answer is useless. In the most important parts, there are dots. My problem is that your "example" doesn't compile. So, what if it is from 2009? Google pointed me to this QA, and I expected to find it helpfull. But it is not. Also, he is not asking for a portable way to do, but using posix.

Comment: Your comment was probably deleted because it was rude.

Answer (score 5):

`std::filebuf` probably has a file descriptor somewhere inside it, but getting at it requires horrible implementation-specific hacks.

Here is one such horrible hack for libstdc++.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

int GetFileDescriptor(std::filebuf& filebuf)
{
  class my_filebuf : public std::filebuf
  {
  public:
    int handle() { return _M_file.fd(); }
  };

  return static_cast<my_filebuf&>(filebuf).handle();
}

int main()
{
  std::ofstream out("test");

  out << "Hello, world!";
  out.flush();

  fsync(GetFileDescriptor(*out.rdbuf()));
}
```

Comment: what is _M_file ?

Comment: @AmruthA - A protected member variable of libstdc++'s implementation of `std::filebuf`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot portably do `fsync()` on a file descriptor open for reading, at all. In Linux, `fsync()` is [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) as generating EBADF if the descriptor is not in write mode.

Comment: Ok, then what if I open it for appending?

Comment: You are not answering the question. The ofstream opens a file for writing, not reading.

Comment: Also, you can fsync() on directory opened in read mode. Actually, that's how you force disk write.