# Does it makes sense to call sync() on output-only fstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ofstream

I found some legacy company code that was using an `std::fstream` and calling `fs.flush()` after each write, then `fs.sync()` each time a certain amount of data were written to the stream. **This code only needs to do output operations, not input ones**.

```cpp
std::fstream fs(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
fs.write(buff, size);
fs.flush();
if (/* needs to sync */) {
  fs.sync();
}
```

This is surprising me as I usually use `std::ofstream` for output-only IO operations and because this class actually does not have the `sync()` method.

Since `std::ofstream` does not have the `sync()` method, does it makes sense to use `std::fstream` and `sync()` for output-only IO operations?

In my specific case, should I keep using `std::ofstream` and call `flush` without thinking about `sync`?

Comment: _calling fs.flush() after each write_ Does it have a reason for doing that?  It will kill performance.

Comment: @PaulSanders The code writes a block (buffer) of 8192 bytes at each iteration. I believe that flushing after each write is to ensure that the maximum of data is stored to avoid loss. But then it still does not really makes sense since the file would end-up partially written anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/ you will find `sync` under the heading "Public member functions inherited from istream" and its description is:

> **Synchronize input buffer**
>
> Synchronizes the associated stream buffer
> with its controlled input sequence.

So no, this is not needed for output-only code and will do nothing useful there.

If from the logic of the code it thinks it is doing a `fsync` equivalent, you would need to do that in a different way. See
[How to do fsync on an ofstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676787/how-to-do-fsync-on-an-ofstream)

Comment: This was my understanding too but the code was confusing

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/sync/ <- I think `sync` is throwing away currently unprocessed characters in the input, in any case, nothing you would need for writing